# Angular ngModel directive binds to `this` instead of `$scope`

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

**Statement:** I have had this problem many times before and it always seems to be random.

**Define Random:** Random as in which properties it does this to, the result is reproducible between debugging sessions, and on multiple environments/browsers.

**Behavior:** My issue is the `textarea` with `ng-model="sometext"` is binding to `this.sometext` instead of `$scope.sometext`. When I enter "`hello"` into the textarea and place a breakpoint in chrome and inspect the value of `$scope.sometext` it is `""` but when I inspect `this.sometext` it is `"hello"`.

**Background:** All of the other properties (not shown for brevity) bind correctly to `$scope` but this specific one does not. I am *not* using `controllerAs`

**Question:** Why does this happen? and how do I fix it so it binds correctly to `$scope` instead of `this`

**Code:**

Controller:

```
1  angular.module 'myApp'
2  .controller 'HomeController', ($scope, Engine) ->
3    $scope.playButtonText = 'Play'
4    $scope.sometext = '' #<- Setting initial value
5
6    $scope.play = ->
7      if $scope.playButtonText is 'Play'
8        $scope.playButtonText = 'Stop'
9        promise = Engine.play $scope.sometext
10       if promise is false
11         $scope.playButtonText = 'Play'
12       else
13         promise.then ->
14           $scope.playButtonText = 'Play'
15     else $scope.playButtonText = 'Play'
```

View:

```
ion-view(title='My Title')
  ion-content
    h2(class='text-center') Enter text, choose playback, choose speed, and press play
    div(class='list')
      label(class='item item-input')
        # THIS TEXTAREA IS THE ONE
        textarea(placeholder='Enter some text to translate', ng-model='sometext')
    button(type='button', class='button button-full button-stable', ng-click='play()') {{playButtonText}}
```

Config:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
.config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
  $stateProvider
  .state 'tab',
    url: "/tab"
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  .state 'tab.home',
    url: '/home'
    views:
      'tab-home':
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html' #<- This is the view
        controller: 'HomeController' #<- This is the controller

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/tab/home'
```

Engine:

```
angular.module 'morsecode'
.factory 'Engine', ($q) ->
  Engine = {}

  Engine.play = (text) ->
    if text.length is 0
      return false
    upper = text.toUpperCase()
    phrase = ''
    for letter in upper
      phrase += Engine.encodeLetter letter
    deferred = $q.defer()
    Engine.loop phrase, 0, Engine, deferred
    return deferred.promise

  return Engine
```

Not sure how the Engine code is relevant, but there it is (methods not related not included, it is rather complex with `setTimeout`s calling `setTimeout`s and lots of recursive code)

Debugging Image:

[image: Debugging Image]

Comment: It would be more useful to have the code for Engine than the config data

Comment: I will add the relevant parts of `Engine` which is a factory. The config was to show how I bind the controller to the view.

Comment: Are you sure Engine.play is not modifying $scope.sometext? You are passing by reference.

Comment: @Luke101 If I set a breakpoint on line 7 of the controller and then inspect the `$scope` object. `sometext` is `""` but if I inspect `this` (which I'm assuming is the controller) then `sometext` is `"hello"`. This is before `Engine.play()` is ever called.

Comment: Never seen this before except when browser cache is not updated. Since, this happens on a random basis it will be tough to debug. Maybe, you can try this. Change ng-click='play()' to ng-click='play(sometext)'. Then add the parameter to the play function in the controller. Then lets see what happens.

Comment: @Luke101 that's a good idea. I can give it a try. I can also try clearing the cache. This isn't the first application I've seen it do this. What I meant by random was that it is just on random properties. Not during random runtimes. No matter how many times I refresh our try again the result is consistent. But why this property compared to the others that are defined and used in exactly the same way...

Comment: @Luke101 Clearing the cache doesn't make a difference... But (obviously) passing the value to `play()` does work, so I will go with that for now... Until I have another issue like this...

Comment: Great, glad you have a work around. But I am still concerned the root problem was not solved. I'll keep think about this one.